# Remove lines around pattern in Vim

Tags: css, vim

There is a css file and I want to make two things:

1) Remove all webkit keyframes and surrounding whitespace characters like:

```
@keyframes outToLeft {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

2) Remove all webkit prefixed properties and surrounding whitespace characters like:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
```

I tries to use %s but it doesn't work (maybe my construction wasn't right)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you want, do you wannt to remove the whole `@keyframes` block on the first example, or just the word and the whitespace?. What about the second example, do you want to remove the whole line?

Comment: I want to remove the whole keyframe and whole property line.

Comment: Hi again, from the comment under my answer it seems like this isn't possible in ideavim. I bet you just solved it in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the global `:g` command.

For your first part, it would look like this:

```
:g/@^keyframes/norm d}
```

which means on every line matching the pattern `^@keyframes` do `norm d}`
`norm` allows to give the block a normal command. `d}` deletes the whole block.

for the second example it is even easier, we can use the `:g` command with the `d` flag:

```
:g/^-webkit/d
```

`d` just means delete.

Since you mentioned whitespaces maybe the lines should look like that:

```
:g/@^keyframes/norm d}dk
```

to delete the line before and after the block, or to keep one line:

```
:g/@^keyframes/norm d}dd
```

the same goes for the second example:

```
:g/^-webkit/norm dj
```

if you want to delete the following line too.

Comment: IdeaVim, as far as I know, does not support the ex :g command. None of the above examples work in IdeaVim.

Comment: @MonteCreasor fair point, I am asking the creator if he solved it in plain vim, and will update the question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible, IdeaVim doesn't support the global g: command.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-831 for more information and updated status.

If replace it with empty line is fine, you could do something like `:%s/.*-webkit.*//g`

Comment: You’re missing an extra slash between / and g there

Comment: Updated. Thanks!